Python CCXT Library: Simple Buy/Sell Function In MEXC
I'm doing a bot that gives order to buy or sell coins (in MEXC), but I have a problem with giving orders.
I tried this code:
import ccxt

api_key = KEY
secret = SECRET

exchange = ccxt.mexc({
    'apiKey': api_key,
    'secret': secret,
    'options': {
        'createMarketBuyOrderRequiresPrice': False,
    }
})

symbol = 'LBTCUSDT'
amount_in_usd = 10


ticker = exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)
current_price = ticker['last']

amount_in_btc = amount_in_usd / current_price

order = exchange.create_order(symbol, 'market', 'buy', amount_in_btc)

print(order)

But it gives:
ccxt.base.errors.InsufficientFunds: mexc {"msg":"Insufficient position","code":30004} error.

Based on the error message you don't have enough cash ($$$) on the account

Thank you i solved it but it's too slow to giving orders
